# how to make dynamic v-if when render in component Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

how to make v-if when rendering to another component to render fast ? i have some case , when i am going to login and after success my `nabvar component` doest change after it finished, i should manually reload it on my client to get `logout button` and it is same also when i delete , i should manually to reload tho i already put `:key` on that component

here is my component in my **login.vue page**

```js
goLogin() {
    if (!this.input || !this.password) {
      this.$swal.fire({
        type: 'error',
        text: `please enter your email/username and password`,
      });
    } else {
      const client = {
        input: this.input,
        password: this.password,
      };
      this.$axios
        .post('/api/user/login', client)
        .then(({
          data
        }) => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
          // vm.$forceUpdate();
          localStorage.setItem('role', data.tryingLogin.role);
          this.$swal.fire({
            type: 'success',
            text: `successfully login`,
          });
          if (data.tryingLogin.role === 'admin') {
            this.$router.replace({
              path: '/admin'
            });
          } else {
            this.$router.push({
              path: '/'
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.$swal.fire({
            type: 'error',
            text: err.response.data.error,
          });
        });
    }
```

and on my Header.vue component, i have `isLogin` props, and i check by if localStorage.getItem("token")  i close the button login and register on `navbar header.vue` and it should show logout button if client has token, but it was not, after succesfuly login, i should reload it to get the button `logout showing`

how to force it to be changed quickly ? to swap show and hide button login and logout ??

i also make props to check login on my `App.vue` and i use all hooks lifecyly to swap login button ans logout , it doesnt changed at all, :(

and it happends when i delete my list also, i should reload it :( 
i hope you guys could give me some help and trick for solve this problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share state between different components your best choice would be to use a state management library like Vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org

You create a store which holds information on whether the user is logged in or not:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isLoggedIn: false
  },
  mutations: {
    TOGGLE_LOGIN_STATUS: (state) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = !state.isLoggedIn;
    }
  }
})
```

When you successfully log in, you change the `isLoggedIn` flag:

```
store.commit('TOGGLE_LOGIN_STATUS');
```

And you can fetch this status from the store in any of your components (it's also reactive, so changes reflect in all of your components) - it has to be a `computed` property:

```
computed: {
  isLoggedIn() { return store.state.isLoggedIn; },
}
```

You can now use `isLoggedIn` in your `v-if` to display a logout button. Just remember to either import your store in your components or make it global (everything you need is in the Vuex's docs).

Another way is using an event bus.

**/src/event-bus.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

Import it in your Login component.

```
import EventBus from '@/event-bus';
```

After getting the token and successfully logging in, emit an event:

```
EventBus.$emit('logged-in', true);
```

Now import EventBus in a component that's receiving the event (your component with logout button) and place a listener in your `mounted` hook:

```
mounted() {
  EventBus.$on('logged-in', payload => {
    this.isLoggedIn = payload;
  })
}
```

Comment: for my project, i should not using Vuex yet, do u have any method with Vue only and without Vuex ?? :D

Comment: Yes, you could also create an event bus. I've updated my answer.

Comment: hmm i will try and be back soon, so the event bus is like a store state ? is that right ??

Comment: oh ya, the mounted hook is in  my header navbar component ? or App.vue ??

Comment: Not really; you use it to emit events inside of your app. Each event has got a name (of your choice) and you can optionally pass a payload (value) together with it. Another component can subscribe (listen to) this particular event (by it's name) and perform certain actions when it's emmited.
The `mounted` hook can be used in all of your components, but in this scenario, you should register the listener in the component where your Logout button is (or your `isLogin` prop - your `Header.vue` if I'm correct);

Comment: bro it was working, without reload, but after i refresh it back to login button :(

Comment: That's why Vuex would be a better solution but you can change your `isLogin` props in `Header.vue` to `!!localStorage.getItem('token')` by default. It evaluates to true if your `localStorage` has got a `token` but what if your token has expired? It would be better to create a function that communicates with your backend by sending the token, the server verifies if the token is valid and returns user data and auth information. If the token is valid, you set your `isLogin` prop to true. You would fire that function in either `created` or `mounted` hook.